# Order sqlalchemy query objects in descending order by a fields digit portion

Tags: python-2.7, sqlalchemy

Is there a way to order objects in my query by descending order the digit portion from a field? e.g. I have a `tag` field in my objects:

```
shape1
shape2
shape13
shape15
shape9
```

I'd like to order so it would give me

```
shape15
shape13
shape9
shape2
shape1
```

Is this possible? Here's what I'm currently doing

```
db_objects = session.query(DatabasePolygon).order_by(desc(DatabasePolygon.tag))
```

The problem is that this will order them in terms of string sorting, so technically 9 is more than 13 in this method. Can apply some function to `order_by` that will simply tell it to do numerical ordering while ignoring non-digits?

Comment: is the `tag` field always `shape[0-9]+` or more like `[a-z]+[0-9]+`?

Comment: @Lee it's always ´shape[0-9] +´

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do something like this:

```
from sqlalchemy import func, NUMERIC
db_objects = session.query(DatabasePolygon)\
    .order_by(func.cast(func.replace(DatabasePolygon.tag, 'shape', ''), 
                        NUMERIC).desc()).all()
```

You probably really want to cast it as `SIGNED` but I'm not quite sure how to do that...